# Setting nullValueMappingStrategy on the mapper / mapper config level for categories of mappings

Tags: mapstruct

MapStruct documentation has the following to say about the sensible defaults chosen for NullValueMappingStrategy.RETURN_DEFAULT:

> Bean mappings: an 'empty' target bean will be returned, with the
>   exception of constants and expressions, they will be populated when
>   present.
>
> Primitives: the default values for primitives will be returned, e.g.
>   false for boolean or 0 for int.
>
> Iterables / Arrays: an empty iterable will be returned.
>
> Maps: an empty map will be returned.

The problem is, we want to be able specify on the @Mapper level that, e.g., Iterables should have NullValueMappingStrategy.RETURN_DEFAULT but not primitives. The reason for this is that an empty iterable is a sensible default for our use case, but 0 is not a sensible default for int. We'd prefer not to have to, e.g., declare:

```
    @IterableMapping(nullValueMappingStrategy = NullValueMappingStrategy.RETURN_DEFAULT)
```

for every iterable we are mapping.

Does MapStruct provide a clean way to do this that I am not finding in the documentation?

Comment: I know this is fairly old but did you ever resolve this? I don't understand why having this declaration on class level is not working, since I understood it to be hierarchical. Having to declare it on every method is fine, but a bit ugly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the above line is actually a copy-paste error in the documentation. To make myself clear: the `NullValueMappingStrategy` only applies to arguments of mapping methods. Not to bean properties. It is **not** possible to define a primitive argument as source in a bean mapping method.

It is however possible to define non-beans as source of a bean mapping method. Like the `mapFrom` method below:

```java
package org.mapstruct.ap.test.bugs._xyz;

import java.util.List;

import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.NullValueMappingStrategy;
import org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers;

@Mapper( nullValueMappingStrategy = NullValueMappingStrategy.RETURN_DEFAULT)
public interface XyzMapper {

    XyzMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(XyzMapper.class);

    Target map(Source source);

    Target mapFrom( Integer myInt, List<Integer> myList);

    class Source {

        private int myInt;
        private List<Integer> myList;

        public int getMyInt() {
            return myInt;
        }

        public void setMyInt(int myInt) {
            this.myInt = myInt;
        }

        public List<Integer> getMyList() {
            return myList;
        }

        public void setMyList(List<Integer> myList) {
            this.myList = myList;
        }
    }

    class Target {

        private int myInt;
        private List<Integer> myList;

        public int getMyInt() {
            return myInt;
        }

        public void setMyInt(int myInt) {
            this.myInt = myInt;
        }

        public List<Integer> getMyList() {
            return myList;
        }

        public void setMyList(List<Integer> myList) {
            this.myList = myList;
        }
    }


}
```

When using the `NullValueMappingStrategy.RETURN_DEFAULT` the mapFrom will return an empty `Target` just as is specified in the documentation.

This line should be removed from the documentation in relation to the NullValueMappingStrategy: `Primitives: the default values for primitives will be returned, e.g. false for boolean or 0 for int.`